# Linq filtering include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the line below, and thinking to filter the CustomersPics `isdeleted == true`. How do I do that?

```
List<Customer> _customer = context.Customers
                                  .Where(r => r.IsDeleted == IsDeleted)
                                  .Include(r=> r.CustomersPics)
                                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Linq To SQL and Entity Framework does not support filtered includes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want with `Include` extension method. You can filter the navigation collection property by using `Load` method like this:

```
var customers = context.Customers.ToList(); // Make to add some Where clause here and avoid loading all data from Customer table :D
foreach(var customer in customers)
{
    context.Entry(customer)
           .Collection(p => p.CustomersPics)
           .Query()
           .Where(p => p.IsDeleted == true)
           .Load();
}
```